# Windows 8 App Store, what's in the update?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

The Windows 8 App Store shows that he has updates. Is there a way to see what its in the single Application update like iOS App Store or some kind of Change Log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the update page, you can select an update and click "View Details" to be taken to the app's page. From there though, it is up to the individual developer to fill in the space with update information. If they choose not to, you will be taken to the app description instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add: If there is more than one App selected for an update the `View Details` button does not show.  Select the `Clear` button, then click on the App you want and you will see the `View Details` button appear.